# Eliminating extra spaces in a hangman game in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote a hangman game in Ruby, yet there are two extra spaces printed out at the end of each word which prevents the program from knowing when the user as won, as well as being confusing to play.  How do I remedy this?  Code:

```
    class HangmanGame
    def initialize(word)
        @word = word
        @current_word = "_" * word.size
    end

    def current_word
        @current_word
    end

    def word
        @word
    end

    def take_guess(guess_ltr)
        @word.split("").each_with_index do |word_ltr, i|
            if word_ltr == guess_ltr.downcase
                @current_word[i] = guess_ltr.downcase
            else 
                print word_ltr
            end
        end
    end

    def done? 
        if @word == @current_word
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end
end


thewordlist = []
file = File.open("5desk.txt")
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the file too?

Comment: The problem could well be occurring due to how you generate and/or read the file of words, or select a word to use. So please give example first few lines of file, and show code that loads the data and assigns to `thewordlist`

Answer (score 0):

While trying to resolve the issue, I also refactored the code a bit though not relevant to the question. So posting it as it may help someone:

```
class Hangman
  attr_reader :word

  def initialize(word)
    @word = word.downcase
    @guesses = []
  end

  def take_guess(c)
    character = c.downcase.strip
    @guesses << character unless @guesses.include? character
  end

  def current_word
    @word.gsub(/[^#{@guesses.join}\s]/, '_')
  end

  def done?
    !(@word.tr(@guesses.join, '*') =~ /\w/)
  end
end
```

Notes:

1. Try to remove instance variables that are absolutely not require. eg `@current_word`
2. Try to use `attr_reader` eg: `@word`
3. Try to normalize input/output as soon as possible at the time of initialization itself. eg: `guess_ltr`
4. Try using simple/expressive variable names. eg `guess_ltr`
5. `current_word` calculates the current state of the game by replacing everything other than the guesses and spaces with `_`.
6. `done?` checks if there is any word character left in `@word` after attempting to replace with the guesses.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to your question but this may be helpful.

Recently I built a ruby gem to play hangman directly on the terminal, it is called `play_hangman`. To build it I used the `hangman_engine` gem, which have implemented the game logic and a view helper to draw the game on the terminal. Check out the code of those libraries, maybe you find them useful.

Code source is here:

- [play_hangman](https://github.com/ammancilla/play_hangman)
- [hangman_engine](https://github.com/ammancilla/hangman_engine)